# Group by in T-SQL for selecting different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have following table `ContactDetails`. This table contains both cell phone as well as emails. These rows can be updated based on Users latest contact details. So `userid` (here 1) can have multiple rows grouped by Email and cell as below. There can be multiple users 2.3.4...so on

Rows are as below

```
   SrNo  Userid  ContactType  ContactDetail     LoadDate
    1    1       Email         x1.y@gmail.com   2013-01-01
    2    1       Cell          12345678         2013-01-01

    3    1       Email         x2.y@gmail.com   2012-01-01
    4    1       Cell          98765432         2012-01-01

    5    1       Email         x2.y@gmail.com   2011-01-01
    6    1       Cell          987654321        2011-01-01
```

I am looking for recent `Email` and `Cell` details of users. I tried running the query as below

```
Select 
   Userid, 
   Max(ContactDetail),
   MAX(LoadDate) 
from 
   ContactDetails 
group by 
   Userid, ContactType;
```

But I understand that this won't work.

Can anyone give some suggestion to pull the latest email and cell in single or sub-queries?

Cheers!
Junni

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to select the most recent row of interest:

```
;With Ordered as (
    select UserId,ContactType,ContactDetail,LoadDate,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY UserID,ContactType
                ORDER BY LoadDate DESC) as rn
    from ContactDetails
)
select * from Ordered where rn = 1
```